# How to convert month wise value into day wise values by dividing month wise value by corresponding number of days in that month in a dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to convert month wise(BP,RE) values into day wise(BP,RE) values by dividing month wise value by corresponding number of days in that month in a dataframe except for one category named `Quality Parameters`.I want to show day wise value for the category named `Quality Parameters` as the same value of month wise value(eg: if `January` month value is `45`, I want to show day wise values from first of January to 31st of January as 45.Similarly for all months).

```
# Converting month-wise data into day-wise data - In Budget file(starts)
distillery_excel_data_upper['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(
    distillery_excel_data_upper['Year'] + distillery_excel_data_upper['Month'], format='%Y%B')
excel_date = pd.to_datetime(distillery_excel_data_upper['Date'])
daywise_excel_data = (distillery_excel_data_upper.assign(Daily=[pd.date_range(*x, freq='D') for x in
                                                                zip(excel_date, excel_date.add(
                                                                    pd.offsets.MonthEnd()))]).explode("Daily"))
daywise_excel_data["BP"] = daywise_excel_data["BP"].apply(pd.to_numeric)
daywise_excel_data["RE"] = daywise_excel_data["RE"].apply(pd.to_numeric)

daywise_excel_data[['BP', 'RE']] = daywise_excel_data[['BP', 'RE']].div(
    daywise_excel_data.groupby(["Date", "Category", "Parameter", "Region", "Factory", "UOM"])[
        'Date'].transform("count"), axis=0)
daywise_excel_data = daywise_excel_data.drop(['Date', 'Year', 'Month'], axis=1)

daywise_excel_data.rename(columns={'Daily': 'date'}, inplace=True)
```

Above code is applicable for all categories.In this `BP`,`RE`,`Category`,`Parameter`,`Region`,`Factory`,`UOM`,`Year` and `Month` are dataframe columns.

Below shows the input dataframe:

```
    Year  Month   Region    Factory  Category         Parameter UOM      BP     RE
0   2023  April  Tamil Nadu   A     Production            ac     L    30.0   60.0
1   2023  April  Tamil Nadu   B     Quality Parameter     acc    L    45.0     20.0
2   2023  April  Karnataka    C     Quality Parameter      bc    L    23.0     50.0
3   2023  May    Karnataka    C     Quality Parameter      bc    L     0.0     43.0
4   2023  June   Karnataka    C     Quality Parameter      bc    L    10.0     56.0
5   2023  June   Karnataka    C     Production             bc    L    60.0     90.0
```

Desired output:

```
  Year  Month    Date     Region    Factory  Category         Parameter UOM      BP     RE
0 2023  April 2023-04-01 Tamil Nadu   A     Production            ac     L       1.0   2.0
0 2023  April 2023-04-02 Tamil Nadu   A     Production            ac     L       1.0   2.0
.. ..   ..       ..       ..          ..       ..     .. .. .. .. 
.. ..   ..       ..       ..          ..       ..     .. .. .. .. 
0 2023  April 2023-04-30 Tamil Nadu   A     Production            ac     L       1.0   2.0
1 2023  April 2023-04-01 Tamil Nadu   B     Quality Parameter     acc    L       45.0  20.0
1 2023  April 2023-04-02 Tamil Nadu   B     Quality Parameter     acc    L       45.0  20.0
.. ..   ..       ..       ..          ..       ..     .. .. .. .. 
.. ..   ..       ..       ..          ..       ..     .. .. .. ..
 
1 2023  April 2023-04-30 Tamil Nadu   B     Quality Parameter     acc    L       45.0  20.0
2 2023  April 2023-04-01 Karnataka    C     Quality Parameter     acc    L       23.0  50.0
2 2023  April 2023-04-02 Karnataka    C     Quality Parameter     acc    L       23.0  50.0
.. ..   ..       ..       ..          ..       ..     .. .. .. .. 
.. ..   ..       ..       ..          ..       ..     .. .. .. ..
2 2023  April 2023-04-30 Karnataka    C     Quality Parameter     acc    L       23.0  50.0
3 2023  May   2023-05-01 Karnataka    C     Quality Parameter     acc    L       0.0   43.0
3 2023  May   2023-05-02 Karnataka    C     Quality Parameter     acc    L       0.0   43.0
.. ..   ..       ..       ..          ..       ..     .. .. .. .. 
.. ..   ..       ..       ..          ..       ..     .. .. .. ..
3 2023  May   2023-05-31 Karnataka    C     Quality Parameter     acc    L       0.0   43.0
4 2023  June  2023-05-01 Karnataka    C     Quality Parameter     acc    L       10.0  56.0
4 2023  June  2023-05-02 Karnataka    C     Quality Parameter     acc    L       10.0  56.0
.. ..   ..       ..       ..          ..       ..     .. .. .. .. 
.. ..   ..       ..       ..          ..       ..     .. .. .. ..
4 2023  June  2023-05-30 Karnataka    C     Quality Parameter     acc    L       10.0  56.0
5 2023  June  2023-05-01 Karnataka    C     Production        acc    L       2.0    3.0
5 2023  June  2023-05-02 Karnataka    C     Production        acc    L       2.0    3.0
.. ..   ..       ..       ..          ..       ..     .. .. .. .. 
.. ..   ..       ..       ..          ..       ..     .. .. .. ..
5 2023  June  2023-05-30 Karnataka    C     Production        acc    L       2.0    3.0
```

Can anyone suggest a solution to achieve this result.

Comment: Please also include in your question an example of how you expect the resulting Dataframe to look like.  This will aid in understanding your question and the logic behind your desired transformation.

Comment: Added desired output. @itprorh66

Comment: Since your sample dataframe only has 4 rows, how to you transform this input to the desired output which see,ms to imply 149 rows?  Why does row 29 of the output seem to repeat row 0 of the input?  Please clarify your logic!

Comment: Each row shows month wise data. I want to split it into day wise data based on year and month. Some month has 30 days, some month has 31 days and for the month February, some year has 28 days and some year has 29 days. Also I want divide monthly RE and BP value by corresponding no.of days of that particular month except category named Quality Parameter. For the category named Quality Parameter, show day wise value as corresponding month wise value. That is same value for all days in that particular month. And the index number is not necessary in the desired output. @itprorh66

Comment: In the code I mentioned above, day wise splitting is done properly. I need to handle the category named Quality Parameter case in the above code@itprorh66

Answer (score 0):

While I think there are probably better ways to approach the date conversion you have shown, I can't offer any suggestions, since you haven't provided a sample of your input data coming from excel.  With this thought out of the way, and understanding that pd.datetime is scheduled for depreciation, I will provide a solution based on use of the dateutil library, which is my goto solution for all things datetime.

So given that you have a dataframe as illustrated in your question and you want as output a dataframe which satisfies the following:

1. Breaks out monthly data on a day basis
2. Divides the input columns BP & RE by the number of days for the current month
3. Evaluates the number of days per month based on recognition of the year

Here is a solution approach:
for each row of input dataframe:

1. compute the number of days in current month
2. compute the relative BP and RE values based on the computed month duration
3. output a row to a new dataframe for each day in month

Here is an approach which follows the above solution methodology.  From a limited set of tests, it seems to satisfy your needs:

```
import pandas as pd
import dateutil as du

def compute_daysperMonth(curmth) -> int:
    # return the number of days in the month
    nxtmth = curmth  + du.relativedelta.relativedelta(months= +1)
    dur = nxtmth - curmth
    return dur.days

def processDataFrame(dfin: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    # compute daywise values for monthly data
    cols = dfin.columns
    cols = cols.insert(2, 'Date')    
    dfout = pd.DataFrame(None, None, columns=cols)
    for r in range(dfin.shape[0]):
        row = dfin.iloc[r]
        start_date = du.parser.parse(f'{row.Month} 01 {row.Year}')
        days = compute_daysperMonth(start_date)
        for d in range(days):
            nwdate = start_date + du.relativedelta.relativedelta(days= d)
            insertData = [row.Year,      # Year
                          row.Month,     # Month
                          nwdte.date(),  # Date
                          row.Region,    # Region
                          row.Factory,   # Factory
                          row.Category,  # Category
                          row.Parameter, # Parameter
                          row.UOM,       # UOM
                          row.BP/days,    # BP
                          row.RE/days    # RE
                         ]
            dfout = pd.concat([dfout,
                             pd.DataFrame(data=[insertData],
                                          columns=cols)],
                            axis=0, ignore_index=True)
            
    return dfout
```

By executing `processDataFrame(df)` the resulting dataframe will satisfy your needs.